# I have been trying to find the accuracy for this data using random forest but is not working though there is no null values

Tags: r, dataframe

[No Na Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrmxS.png)

[0 Null values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTte3.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2uHx.png)

```
#6. Building a RandomForest model
SalePrice = train$SalePrice
SalePrice = as.factor(SalePrice)
house_model <-library(randomForest)
house_model <-randomForest(SalePrice~.,
                            data = train,na.action = na.exclude)
#using na.exclude on the whole data frame at once in order to keep observations same accross all variables
#Lets, predict the data now
prediction <- format(round(predict(house_model,test)))
prediction
rf <-randomForest(SalePrice~.,data=train, ntree=500) 
print(rf)
#sum(is.na(train$SalePrice))
```

> Here, the error is missing value in the object which I don't see any

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: even if remove the factor and use the numeric value the error still is the same

Comment: Try `na.omit` instead of `na.exclude`. Or try actually remove `NA` values from the data, `train = na.omit(train)`.